# Don't understand the inner callback in async.parallel()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need help understanding `async.parallel(tasks, callback)`.

From what I understand, the list of tasks are executed, and once they're finished, all the results are then passed to `callback`.

An example of it in action is:

```
async.parallel([
  function(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Task One');
      callback(null, 1); <----- DON'T UNDERSTAND
    }, 200);
  },
  function(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Task Two');
      callback(null, 2); <----- DON'T UNDERSTAND
    }, 100);
  }
],
function(err, results) {
  console.log(results);
  // the results array will equal [1, 2] even though
  // the second function had a shorter timeout.
```

});

The part that I don't understand however, are the inner calls to `callback`. Specifically, what does it mean when we call `callback(null, 1)` and `callback(null, 2)`? What do the `null` and the `1` or `2` refer to?

Comment: `null` means there wasn't any errors when executing that individual task, and `1,2 ...` are the final results of the individual tasks.